# Put transperent fragment on layout in android

Tags: android, layout

I've a main.xml layout as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <FrameLayout>/FrameLayout>

   <RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>

   <fragment></fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I've to put transparent fragment/layout over main layout so I can put here some controllers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <fragment></fragment>
   <RelativeLayout>
      <!-- Your controllers go here -->
   </RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

The frame laoyut will allow the relative layout and the fragment to be on top of each other.
adding the relative layout after the fragment grants the controls are visible.